# How to improve string parser method for 2 columns (reading 2 string on a line)

Tags: java, string, io

```
public class testing_string {


public static void read_doc_word(String line){             
    String doc_id = "" ;
    String word_id = "" ;
    boolean doc_id_ends = false ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < line.length() ; i++){
       if(line.charAt(i) == 9) doc_id_ends = true ; // 9 is TAB in asci 
       else if(doc_id_ends == false) doc_id += line.charAt(i) ;   
       else if( doc_id_ends == true) word_id += line.charAt(i) ;               
    }

    System.out.println("doc id " + doc_id ) ;
    System.out.println("word id " + word_id ) ;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "1   29" ;
        read_doc_word(x) ;  
}
```

}

Input: every line has 2 numbers.
What is better way to do it? 
I want to avoid the ugly "doc_id += line.charAt(i) " , 
concatenating every char to string.

How do I just do this:

- read the whole string before tab
- skip tab
- read the whole stringafter tab

**or only way is to check every char? (like I did)** I d like to avoid checking every char!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `String.split()`.

Please refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) documentation.

So your code can be modified as follows:

```
    public static void read_doc_word(String line){             
    String doc_id = "" ;
    String word_id = "" ;
    String[] split ;

    split = line.split("\\t");

    if(split.length==2){
        doc_id = split[0];
        word_id = split[1];
    }

    System.out.println("doc id " + doc_id ) ; \\ 1
    System.out.println("word id " + word_id ) ; \\29

}
```

Please note that in order to split by tab, you need to use the regular expression `"\\t"` and not just `"\t"`.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Example (replace comma with tab):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "1,29";
    String[] splitted = example.split(",");

    System.out.println(splitted[0]); // 1
    System.out.println(splitted[1]); // 29
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the `String` on all whitespace, which includes tabs:

```
public static void read_doc_word(String line){       
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println("Doc ID:" + tokens[0]);
    System.out.println("Word ID:" + tokens[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Path path = Paths.get("path", "to", "my", "document");
    Files.lines(path).map((l) -> l.split("\t")).forEach((s) -> {
        System.out.println("doc id " + s[0]);
        System.out.println("word id " + s[1]);
    });
}
```

More seriously, you can just split on tab:

```
public static void read_doc_word(final String line){             
    final String[] split = line.split("\t");
    final String doc_id = split[0] ;
    final String word_id = split[1] ;
    System.out.println("doc id " + doc_id ) ;
    System.out.println("word id " + word_id ) ;    
}
```

It is also worth noting that you should **never do `String` concatenation in a loop**. This is [amazingly slow](http://kaioa.com/node/59). So even if there wasn't a `String.split` method your method could still be improved upon.

Comment: @ERJAN it is currently still in beta, due for release this month.